# How to access non-username specific YouTube Channel JSON Feed?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api, feed

I'm trying to access the video feed for a particular user account. This user has uploaded 3 videos but their 'channel' page doesn't appear to have a username like other channels?

The process I've used previously is:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=CHANNEL_NAME&alt=json
```

...where CHANNEL_NAME would be the name of the channel.

But the channel I'm trying to access doesn't have a name, I can view the channel via the following URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgZ_C3_ItNfHpC6Wf3hDGgQ
```

...but as you can see it has a code for the user rather than an identifier name.

So trying to use the following doesn't bring back the actual feed:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=UCgZ_C3_ItNfHpC6Wf3hDGgQ&alt=json
```

Can any one advise how I would access this feed? I have access to this user's account so could/should I be able to set-up a proper identifier name for the channel?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I've since logged into the user's account and given them a unique username:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/ITECLEARNTECH
```

But I've also found an XML feed version `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ITECLEARNTECH/uploads` from the Google Documentation that seems to include all their videos, but I'm not sure how I can convert this into JSON data (which would be better for me using JavaScript to interact with the feed data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I clearly was being an idiot. Seems I just needed to add `?alt=json` to the end of the URL

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ITECLEARNTECH/uploads?alt=json

I could have sworn I tried that originally and it didn't work, but now it appears it does.

So there you go!